# ag-Grid: set color to FloatingFiler

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am wondering if I could set color to Floating Filter of ag-Grid(picture below), it would be more user-friendly.

[image]

If anyone knows, please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

The `cellRenderer` should help you:

```
cellRenderer: function (params) {
  let eHeaderCell = params.eHeaderCell;
  eHeaderCell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Comment: @TikChiku Can you create a stackblitz? It will be hard to help without it.